# How to install mysql-server 5.6 on RHEL 5.8 (when MySQL-server 5.0 is already installed)

Tags: rhel, yum, mysql, rpm

I want to install mysql-server 5.6 on RHEL 5.8, but when trying `rpm -i` or `rpm -Uvh` it complains that I already have version 5.0 on there. I am happy to replace, upgrade or install another instance.

Comment: Have you searched or tried anything else around accomplishing this?

Comment: I also tried MySQL's yum repo, but it seems to not have version 5.6  This sounded easy before I began actually trying to do it.  It has been surprisingly tough.  Perhaps I should just do yum erase mysql-server and then rpm -i the RPM that I have.

Comment: That's what I would do, especially if you have the DB and .conf files backed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done the follow routines and upgraded to Mysql-server 5.5 successfully on CentOS 6.5.

1. yum remove mysql mysql-*
2. rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
3. rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
   (choose your relevant Remi repo)
4. yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install mysql mysql-server
5. service mysqld start
6. mysql_upgrade -u root -p